# Problem with IE8: p elements have a padding/margin that wont go away!

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix an issue only to do with IE8, not any other version of IE or Firefox etc.

**Edit** An example of my problem can be seen here http://kazcare.com/kamaleiexample/learningEnvironment.html

A paragraph element has a margin or padding on top that wont go away. Please dont say use inline css because I have tried that & it doesn't change it.

You see if I do this

```
<p class="subHeading" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Our Philosophy</p>
```

The top margin/padding shows only on IE8 when there shd be none. Note: the p element is nested inside a element with the class pageBoxContent that does set the margin-top.

My css:

```
.pageBoxContent p { font-family:Calibri, "Myriad Pro", Serif; margin: 0; margin-top: 10px; }
.subHeading { color: #6D4F9B; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px;  margin-top: 0; }
```

Comment: The problem is obviously caused by the context of the object in the page so there's no way for us to help without you sharing that context.  Create the smallest piece of HTML/CSS that shows the problem and put it in a jsFiddle so we can see the issue.

Comment: @thirtydot - What do you mean about his account?

Comment: @tw16: Hover over the link for "Mack" that asked the question, and "Mack" that edited it.

Comment: @thirty theoretically SO will detect one as a puppet account and merge them.

Comment: @ErikE: Looks like you're right: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89694/why-have-my-two-accounts-been-merged-without-asking-me/89790#89790. I wasn't aware.

Comment: @tw6 The two accounts have different rep, so it was not so hard for him...

Answer (score 2):

On the website in the code you have written `<b class="subheading">` not `<p class="subheading">`. Try replacing the **b** with a **p**.

The extra margin problem is actually the image you used as the container's top. Located inside `.mainPageBox` and above `.pageBoxContent`. The white space above the subheading is actually part of the image.

```
<img alt="" src="images/pageBoxTop.png" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" class="pageBoxTop">
```